# Can´t validate app project after archiveing it.

Tags: ios, validation

Hi i´m having a problem trying to upload my app to the appstore and it feels like i´v looked everywhere. Asking this question was not my fist choice but I can´t se any other solution. My problem is that the validate button is grayed out aswell as the upload to appstore button. I have done every step with appids and certificates very carefully and precise. what can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqhLs.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not AppStore account support.

Comment: @KenWhite I can´t find any help at the Appstore suport. Please help

Comment: That doesn't magically change an off-topic question to on-topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: @kenWhite no that is true but do you know why I can´t click validate?

Answer (score 0):

I may hace found an answer and it reads: If you select an archive in the Archives window and the Validate, Export, or “Upload to App Store” buttons are disabled, verify that the archive contains a single top-level app.

But what I don´t understand is what single top-level app is. Can someone explain?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html